# Define a NameSpace in VB

Tags: vb.net

I want to define a unified namespace for all my classes and put them all in it.
I did it with

```
Namespace
...
End Namespace
```

But now I can not import it in other projects, also I can not import it in another file in my main project (That file is not in my namespace it is just UI).

Thank you in andvance !

Comment: Did you add the right reference to the project?

Comment: It's not going to be in the references. You simply need to have the right `Imports` at the top of your file.

Comment: A reference is a dll or an other project. A namespace is visible from the list of all references.

Comment: What is right import ? i wrote Import namespace name , but did not recognized

Comment: Are you trying to use these classes in the same project or a different project?

Comment: in a same project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your project has a **root namespace** defined in the project properties. Let's say this root namespace is `MyApp.MyProject`.

Then inside this project, you have a class defined like this:

```
Namespace MyNamespace

    Public Class MyClass...

End Namespace
```

If you want to use MyClass inside another class, you would just add the following Imports statement at the top of the file:

```
Imports MyApp.MyProject.MyNamespace
```

You could also define a Namespace globally outside of the root namespace of your project with [`Global`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/program-structure/namespaces#global-keyword-in-namespace-statements) like so:

```
Namespace Global.MyNamespace
    ...
End Namespace
```

More information can be found in the [.NET documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/program-structure/namespaces)

Comment: It's worth mentioning that, if you want to define or specify a namespace which is not under the root namespace, you still can do that by prefixing it with `Global` (e.g. `Namespace Global.MyOtherNamespace`)

Comment: @StevenDoggart Actually it is what I need , Thank you !

Comment: @FASW Using global namespace should be discouraged. There is little need for it. The more you put there, the more it becomes muddied. It's best practice to avoid naming collisions and have structured namespaces.

Comment: @FalcoGer: Yeah I don't get why you would need a global namespace either. Personally I never used it.

Comment: On VB Projects, I generally clear the root namespace and just use the `Namespace` statements.  This makes it similar to the way C# does it.

Comment: Thank You for the hint with Global definition @StevenDoggart